# Post to Facebook wall without using PHP-SDK?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I don't want to add SDK to my project, but I want to post messages to FB Page (public page, not /me).
As I understood I need to do smt like this

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Check out this funny article' \
     -F 'link=http://www.example.com/article.html' \
     -F 'picture=http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg' \
     -F 'name=Article Title' \
     -F 'caption=Caption for the link' \
     -F 'description=Longer description of the link' \
     -F 'actions={"name": "View on Zombo", "link": "http://www.zombo.com"} \
     -F 'privacy={"value": "ALL_FRIENDS"} \
     https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

How I can get access token key for that?
When I use token from request https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxx&client_secret=yyy it says that it token can be used only for client info (client_credintials).
I need another grant_type, or another params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your version you would need the publish_stream permission from the user, which would only work if you have requested the perm. so you would need js SDK or php (or any other serverside) SDK

you can make it even more simpler if you just to this url:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Dialogs%20provide%20a%20simple,%20consistent%20interface%20for%20applications%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ or http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/ for more examples.

Comment: But I thought that's why I use access tokens.
In our "facebook-like" social network I just get token (once) for my app and then use it to post messages.

Comment: or are you trying to post to facebook in "your" name. like autocrossposts from an CMS. this would work, but you need a sdk for it. (you "can" do it without but its more work)

Comment: Yep, in "my" name, but not to mine wall. As I said, I don't want to use SDK (useless code as I saw).

Comment: ok have fun reading through http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ you will need to create an app, get an app access_token your user will need the appropiiate rights. after that you can post to your users walls, fan pages your are admin of, (and to walls of your friends afaik) without you needed to be logedin. but this is to much to be anwered here.

Answer (score 0):

All I wanted to know is:

1) Auth app in dialog:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&scope=publish_stream,offline_access&redirect_uri=http://site.com
```

2) Get "forever" access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxx&client_secret=yyy&code=zzz&redirect_uri=http://site.com
```

3) Post to wall:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=aaa&message=msg
```