# Twitter update status with OAuth without SDK

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I need to update twitter status by php-curl w/out any SDK.
What url and parameters should I use (I've already created app and generated access token)?
And I don't want to implement OAuth lib.
All I want to do is smth like this: [Post to Facebook wall without using PHP-SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124256/post-to-facebook-wall-without-using-php-sdk) (last post)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use an SDK ? You'll have to implement OAuth, which is not really easy.

You could try to use [Zend_Oauth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html) for example. This is a Zend component, it only depends on `Zend_Http`, you don't have to use the whole framework. You could optionally use `Zend_Service_Twitter` too.

Comment: I don't want to include SDK as I think this is a useless code.
I already done simular with facebook, only one curl request to one URL. Without that OAuth objects etc...

Comment: Facebook is using OAuth2, which is very simple compared to OAuth1 (which Twitter is using). In Oauth2 you just have to add a query parameter to each URL; in OAuth1 you have to sign your urls with the consumer secret. Read Zend_Oauth code.

Comment: Ok. Not 1 request, but 2: authorize, get tokens, then post.
But they are still two(three) simple requests.

Comment: You also have to **sign** your requests with HMAC or RSA, the token itself is not enough.

Comment: It's not a problem at all. It's still simple requests) I'm asking about what parameters is used, I'm watching Abrahams OAuth lib and can't find out how parameters (consumer key, consumer secret) are called in "token request" request